# Is there an API monitoring tool with access token renewal mechanism?

Tags: apimonitor

Looking for an API monitoring tool for uptime checking/response fields validation.

Tried all below, but seems none handle authentication with automatic token renewal

- [assertible](https://assertible.com)
- [grafana](https://grafana.com/)
- [checkly](https://www.checklyhq.com/)

Is there anything that supports `automatic token renewal workflow`?

seems like closest one to me is url-based fetching in [assertible setup](https://assertible.com/docs/guide/tests#setup-steps)